Uniqueness of solution for a wave equation in a rectangular domain
I am trying to solve the following problem.
Consider the following boundary value problem for wave equation:
$u_{tt}=u_{xx}\quad (0<x<l_1 \text{ and } 0<t<l_2)$
$u(0,t)=u(l_1,t)=0 \quad(0<t<l_2)$
$u(x,0)=u(x,l_2)=0\quad (0<x<l_1)$
Assume that $l_2/l_1$ is a rational number. Determine if the solution of the rectangle is unique or not in the given rectangle.
I tried to prove the uniqueness of solution by using the separation method which will lead to two ODE systems. I did not have any result. But, now I am also thinking that it might not be unique. Could you help me in addressing this question either by proving the uniqueness or provide a counterexample.
Thank you in advance!
Update:
I still did no get how to approach this problem yet.  I started solving using the separation method. I found that $X(x)= \sin( n\pi x/l_1)$ but when I solved for $T(t)$, I found that $T_n(t)= C_1 \sin( n\pi t/l_1)+ C_2 \cos ( n\pi t/l_1))$. When I tried to use the conditions  $u(x,0)=u(x,l_2)=0$, I found that $A_n=B_n=0  \text { and } u_n(x,t)=0$. So does it means that the solution is unique and it is $0$ or I am missing something.
